# How do I use slim framework route get all .. but not include except string

Tags: php, regex, slim

How do I use slim framework route get all   .. but not include except string `get` `/login`

```
$app->get('/.*?', function () use ($uri, $app) {
    $app->redirect($uri['public'].'/login');
});
$app->get('/login', function () use ($uri, $app) {
    echo 'login view';
});

...
$app->post('/login', function () use ($uri, $app) {
    $user_controller = new controller\user_controller();
    $user_controller_login = $user_controller->login($uri, $app);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slim routes are processed in order, so if you define the `/login` route before the catch-all, it will work in that order:

```
$app->get('/login', function() use($app) { ... });
$app->post('/login', ...);

$app->get('/.*', function() use($app) {  $app->redirect('/login'); });
```

Although, I don't usually see 'catch all' style routes. Usually, you'd use URL rewriting to pass to static files not served by routes, and if you're doing this to ensure the user has logged-in to each page, you are better off using Slim Middleware to handle that.

For instance, if you had an authenticate piece of middleware, it could check on each of your routes for a login session/cookie/whatever, and if not found redirect to the login page (also passing the current url so they could be redirected back after login).

```
$authenticate = function() {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    return function() use($app) {
        // check for auth here somehow
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $app->redirect('/login');
        }
    };
 }

 // Use middleware on your defined routes
 $app->get('/stuff', $authenticate, function() use($app) { ... });
 ...
```

Comment: thanks for reply!! I use your suggestion Slim Middleware, I have problem  when return function in authenticate nothing happen so I change function just echo 'test'; but still shows nothing

Comment: I'd need to see your code to diagnose.  The authenticate function shouldn't output anything - it should just return or redirect/pass to a different route.

Comment: I change the `$app->get('/stuff', $authenticate, function() use($app) { ... });` to `$app->get('/stuff', $authenticate(), function() use($app) { ... });` it works!!

Comment: Good to hear.  That's a much cleaner route to go for authentication with Slim.  I just forgot the parens in my example